# jquery check items if the parent list item is not hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a "select all" checkbox. I want to iterate for each checkbox that contains the class `cb-org` and set the `checked` property but only if the parent list item element does not have the class `hidden` applied to it.

The reason for this is because I have a client-side filter so not all list items are visible and I don't want my "select all" to set the `checked` property for items that are currently hidden.

```js
$('#organisations-selectall').change(function() {
  $('.cb-org').each(function (i, obj) {
    if (!$(obj).parent('li').hasClass('hidden')) {
      $(obj).prop('checked', this.checked);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>
     <input id="org-filter" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input id="organisations-selectall" type="checkbox">
        <strong>Select All</strong>
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="attr-org-entity hidden">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org">
        Org 1
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="attr-org-entity">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org">
        Org 2
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="attr-org-entity">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org">
        Org 3
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have an error? Please describe what isn't working.

Comment: Hello, I have no errors on my web page. I think the problem is with `$(obj)` but I am not sure.

Comment: Change `parent('li')` to `closest('li')` and it should most likely work.  The `li` is not the direct parent of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilized jQuery's inherient looping so you do not have to write it yourself.

1. Find all the checkbox
2. Get their parent li, no matter how high up the DOM Tree it is
3. Filter the li to get only those without the `hidden` class
4. For the filtered li, find their nested checkbox
5. Change their checked property

```js
$('#organisations-selectall').change(function(e) {
  $('.cb-org')
    .closest('li')
    .filter(':not(.hidden)')
    .find('.cb-org')
    .prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```css
.hidden { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>
     <input id="org-filter" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input id="organisations-selectall" type="checkbox">
        <strong>Select All</strong>
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="attr-org-entity hidden">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org">
        Org 1
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="attr-org-entity">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org">
        Org 2
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="attr-org-entity">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org">
        Org 3
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```